# Fetch all values based on key in multidimensional array Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

Input Array :

```
   [
     Object { 
               kid="16145", 
               tid="5045", 
               kname="best landlord insurance rates", more...
     }, 
     Object { 
            kid="22586", 
            tid="5045", 
            kname="car insurance deals", more...
    }, 
    Object { 
            kid="49004", 
            tid="5045", 
            kname="landlord and tenant insurance", more...
    }
 ]
```

In above array i need to fetch all values having key 'kid'.

required Output :

```
     array(16145,22586,490004);
```

**Without looping the input array

using array map or array search or any other JS array/Object functions only

Thanks.

Comment: *"Without looping the input array"* is an irrational, and impossible, requirement. *"using array map or array search or any other JS array/Object functions only"* Those loop the array!

Comment: `array.map(function(x) { return x.whatever })`

Answer (score 1):

Note that this is not a multi-dimensional array. It's a simple array of objects.

If **all** of the objects have a `kid` property, then it's a trivial use of `map`:

```
var values = theArray.map(function(entry) { return entry.kid; });
```

If only **some** of the objects have a `kid` property, then `forEach`:

```
var values = [];
theArray.forEach(function(entry) {
    if (entry.hasOwnProperty("kid")) {
        values.push(entry.kid);
    }
});
```

Note that both options loop through the array, which is unavoidable.

Answer (score 1):

It can be like this

```
var newArray = yourArray.map(function(obj) {
    return obj.kid;
});
```

Reference [MDN javascript .map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)